# Read-Only error: Convert all sheets of an xls workbook into separate CSV files

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, xls

I have to convert an xls workbook with multiple sheets in it into CSV format.
The programming language I'm using is VBScript, and thus far the code below gives a 'cannot access read-only document' error.

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
'xls is the path to the xls file
WScript.Echo xls
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(xls)

Dim Worksheet
For Each Worksheet in oBook.Sheets
    If oExcel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        Worksheet.SaveAs strPath & "\" & Worksheet.Name & ".csv", 6
    End If
Next

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: I've tried to find similar questions on stackoverflow, but they're all slighlty different and couldn't solve this problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Additional information: The workbook is 144MB and NOT read-only.

Comment: Where do you get the error?? which line??

Comment: The error occurs in line 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strPath is never set in your code. Your comment says xls is the path to the workbook. It needs to be the full file specification to open the workbook.

Worksheet is a class in Excel.Application. Use

```
Dim oWorksheet 
For Each oWorksheet in oBook.Sheets
    If oExcel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(oWorksheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        oWorksheet.SaveAs oBook.Path & "\" & oWorksheet.Name & ".csv", 6
    End If
Next
```